# Pick the random value from slice and print on cli

Tags: go, slice, glide-golang

How to pick the random value from slice in golang and i need to display it to cli.I have string which i converted to string array by splitting it. Now i want to choose random string from string array and display to user in cli and i need to ask user to input that particular string which is displayed on screen
and compare the user entered input.

```
 string randgen := ‘na gd tg er dd wq ff  gen  vf ws’
 s:= String.split(randgen,””)
 s = [“na”, “gd”, ”er”, “tg”, “er”, “dd”, “wq”, “ff”, “gen”, “vf”, “ws”]
```

Comment: Use math/rand.Intn(len(s)).

Comment: what did you try that was not working?

Comment: No, i am trying to pick random string and display to cli. i am unable shuffle and print it

Comment: Your code doesn't even compile. Please spend some time coming up with a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that you need help with.

Answer (score 1):

There are some issues with your code. You shouldn't define the type when initializing a variable using `:=`.

Also, it's not recommended to depend on spaces to construct and split your slice, as it's not clear what will happen if for example you have multiple spaces, or a tab between the characters instead.

This is a minimal solution that 'just works'.

```golang
package main

import (
        "fmt"
        "math/rand"
        "strings"
        "time"
)

func main() {
        randgen := `na gd tg er dd wq ff gen vf ws`
        s := strings.Split(randgen, " ")
        fmt.Println(s)

        rand.Seed(time.Now().UnixNano())
        randIdx := rand.Intn(len(s))

        fmt.Println("Randomly selected slice value : ", s[randIdx])
}
```

I would suggest reading the [rand](https://golang.org/pkg/math/rand) package documentation for an explanation of what `rand.Seed` does. Also, take a look at the [`shuffle`](https://golang.org/src/math/rand/rand.go?s=7456:7506#L225) function available in `rand`, as it's suited to your problem, if you want to build a more robust solution.

Comment: thank you, i tried above code, it choose the first letter from the slice.

Comment: Each time you run it, it will choose and print a different item in the slice. Eg. in the first run it might choose and print `dd`, the second time `na` and one third time `gen`. Is this what you'd expect? Run it locally, as the Go Playground has an issue with `rand` because time is constant.